# Django Production Server ModelForm help_texts

Tags: django, django-forms

I've got a somewhat weird bug occurring on my production server.  On the local dev server, my ModelForm help texts are working fine, while on the production server, only the default ModelForm help texts are showing.

The Form:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = [
            'name',
            'types',
            'origin',
            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            'description',
            'status',
            'tags',
            'notes',
        ]

        widgets = {
            'start_date': forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y', attrs={'class':'datePicker'}),
            'end_date': forms.DateInput(format='%m/%d/%Y', attrs={'class':'datePicker'}),
        }

        help_texts = {
            'start_date' : 'If you only know the year, enter an approximate start date, such as 01/01/2012',
            'end_date' : 'If you only know the year, enter an approximate start date, such as 01/01/2012',
        }
```

I've double checked all pip requirements, versions are all the same.  I've restarted the server, etc.  I can remove a field from the fields list and when the page is refreshed the field is removed, but still no help texts.  Any Ideas?

### Edit:

Keep in mind that the rest of the project is working fine.  The only noticable difference between the dev and production version is the form help_text only shows the default.

index.wsgi:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/abercrrl/.virtualenvs/cdh_at/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/path/to/cdh_at')
sys.path.append('/path/to/cdh_at/cdh_at')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'cdh_at.settings'

#Activate your virtual env
activate_env = os.path.expanduser("/home/abercrrl/.virtualenvs/cdh_at/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

httpd.conf:

```
....
WSGIScriptAlias /cdh_at /path/to/cdh_at/cdh_at/index.wsgi

<Directory /path/to/cdh_at/cdh_at/index.wsgi>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /cdh_at/static/ /path/to/cdh_at/static/
<Directory /path/to/cdh_at/static/>
Allow from all
</Directory>
....
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv ?

Comment: Yes, and the wsgi file ensures to use the virtualenv

Comment: Updated question with wsgi and httpd.conf setup

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is due to internationalisation, try this:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

help_texts = {
    'start_date' : _('If you only know the year, enter an approximate start date, such as 01/01/2012'),
    'end_date' : _('If you only know the year, enter an approximate start date, such as 01/01/2012'),
}
```